# How can I override a module-defined view and export to code?

Tags: views, 6, features

I'm using [nrembrowser](http://drupal.org/project/nrembrowser) to provide a media library and allow users to insert media via a wysiwyg interface. The module provides its own view which I've altered. I keep my views in code (using features) but I don't know any way to override an existing module-defined view via code (ie something similar to strongarm, but instead of overriding a variable, it's overriding a view). I've solved the problem by using a nrembrowser hook to change the view to my custom one, but I'd be interested in knowing if I could've overridden the module's default view in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [hook_views_default_views_alter()](http://views.doc.logrus.com/group__views__hooks.html#gcd31035a6ae9c7baf05ad034d6a65768). There's [a page on this](http://drupal.org/node/1014774) on drupal.org. As far as I know there's no way to have features automatically export an overridden view and put it in a hook_views_default_views_alter(), and [it looks like there's actually an issue](http://drupal.org/node/766264) with using features together with this hook.